# Login Design Logic

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

This is a pretty generic question, but any advice is appreciated.

I am writing an Ionic2 app that uses Firebase Authentication.

A user can sign up to the app. A verification email is sent to the user's email address. If the user verifies their email, they can access the app.

However, if a user does not verify their email, for example if they signed in with the incorrect email address, then the email will never be verified. In such a case, the incorrectly registered email address sits on the Firebase database redundantly, or if the valid user tries to signup with that email, they get a message that that email address belongs to the original provider (Facebook, Google or plain email), and cannot sign up as a different provider.

As you can see, the above situation can potentially block a user from registering their email address.

I have tried to delete the Firebase account when the user comes to sign in so they start afresh as I do have the matching `uid`. However, I don't think the AngularFire2 api allows a Firebase account to be deleted by `uid`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557686/angularfire2-delete-user-for-a-uid).

Can either suggest:

1. How to delete the account by `uid`, or
2. Another design I can use to resolve this issue.

Thanks you

**UPDATE**

Thank you for the advise below.  I have a Java server which I would like to do the Firebase Admin management of users.

I have found Java [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup) on how to initialize Firebase Admin. e.g.

```
public void initialize() {
    String keyPath = "/appname-123456-firebase-adminsdk-eknji-3071d579f5.json";

    InputStream serviceAccount;
    ClassLoader loader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
    serviceAccount = loader.getResourceAsStream(keyPath);
    // serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(keyPath);
    FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
            .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
            .setDatabaseUrl("https://appname-123456.firebaseio.com").build();
    FirebaseApp app = FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
}
```

I can find Node.js [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user) on how to manage users. But how do you do this in Java?  i.e. How do I delete a user by `uid`?

**UPDATE**

Looks like you need to create a custom token with the `uid`. See [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).

How do you do the following in Java?

```
admin.auth().deleteUser(uid)
  .then(function() {
    console.log("Successfully deleted user");
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log("Error deleting user:", error);
  });
```

**UPDATE**

I don't think it is possible to manage accounts in Java. I think the custom token needs to be passed back to the client, and then used to sign in for that user. see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/custom-auth).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three ways to delete a Firebase Authentication account:

1. from the [Firebase Authentication console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/authentication/users).
2. by calling [`delete()` on the signed in user from the app](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#delete_a_user).
3. by [calling `deleteUser()` from the Admin SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#delete_a_user).

It sounds like you're looking for option 3. This requires that you run a trusted process that deletes the extraneous users. **Don't** try to run this code in your actual app, since that would open up a security that allows all your app's users to delete each other's account.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, option 3 looks like what I need. I will try it out.

Comment: Hi Frank, I am taking your advise and not running admin tasks from the app itself. So I am going to let a Java Server I have do the work. Only problem is, I cannot find any documentation or examples on how to do this in Java (Lots of examples in Node.js). Please see my UPDATE above. If you could offer any advise, I would appreciate it.

Comment: That means the functionality is currently only available in node.js. We'd like to add it to the Java Admin SDK at some point, but there is no timeline for when that will be.

Comment: Thank you Frank. I am now sending the customToken back to the client, and the client deletes the Firebase user.